# Simply python script to get youtube video not working

Tags: python, api, youtube, request, urllib

I am trying to make a script that gets the first yt video result from a search term

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re

query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query" : input()})
html_content = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.youtube.com/results?" + query_string)
search_results = re.findall(r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())
print("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + search_results[0])
```

is giving the error:

````
Exception has occurred: IndexError
list index out of range
  File "C:\Users\redacted\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\yttest.py", line 8, in <module>
    print("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + search_results[0])
    ```
````

Comment: Try importing urllib.request?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to update this post, i figured that out but there is a new error

Comment: You should format your post's code next time for easier readability

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can format your post with ``` to look better

Comment: @Bigweld here, more information about [formatting your code in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

```py
search_results = re.findall(r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})',
                            html_content.read().decode())
```

Like the error clearly mentions, the list index is out of range, i.e., the list is empty. The `re.findall` function in the above line in your code returns an empty list. Check your regex expression.